# WordPress How to append data into post_content after first image?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[image]

I want to append some data after first image retrieved from post_content.

```
add_action('the_post', function($post, $query){
$post->post_content = catch_that_image();
},10,2);

function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];

$chtml = "YOUR DATA GOES HERE";
return "<img src='".$first_img."'>" . "  " . $chtml;
}
```

I am trying to do this by using code. Using this I am unable to append content after first image from post_content.

Comment: Can you provide some more info on the issue with your code? Do you get an error or the text is not displayed but first-image is displayed or both text and first-image are not displayed?

Comment: text is displyed but also appending original content with new content. It means from starting to NEW ADDED CONTENT it is displayed 2 times.